# Error in gtest-printers.h while intergrating GTest to my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

Iam getting the following error while building my project

```
C:\gtest\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest/gtest-printers.h(327) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
C:\gtest\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest/gtest-printers.h(376) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<const void>(testing::internal::IsNotContainer,testing::internal::true_type,T *,std::ostream *)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=const void
    ]
    C:\gtest\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest/gtest-printers.h(416) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void testing::internal::PrintTo<To>(const T &,std::ostream *)' being compiled
    with
    [
        To=const void *,
        T=const void *
    ]
C:\gtest\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest/gtest-printers.h(327) : warning C4826: Conversion from 'const void *' to 'testing::internal::UInt64' is sign-extended. This may cause unexpected runtime behavior.
```

I have initialized InitGoogleTest as follows,

```
void startGTest()
{

char *option[] = { "test.exe", //it doesn't have meaning, just dummy
               "--gtest_output=xml:gTestResults.xml" };
int argc = 2;

testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, option);
RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 
}
```

Some more info,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
char *option[] = { "test.exe", //it doesn't have meaning, just dummy
           "--gtest_output=xml:gTestResults.xml" };
int myargc = 2;
testing::InitGoogleTest(&myargc, option);
RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 
getchar(); // keep console window open until Return keystroke
}
```

Also throws the error,

```
1>c:\...\gtestfactorial\gtestfactorial\gtestfactorial.cpp(4) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
```

If the compiler setting is changed as follows in the project property,

c/c++ -> Treating warning as errors -> NO

Then iam able to Build and run.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're getting this error because you're cross compiling for a 32 bit platform on a 64 bit machine. I get it as well and this is exactly what I'm doing. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235307%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) from Microsoft says

> This warning indicates that the compiler performed sign extension when
>   a 32-bit pointer was cast to a 64-bit variable.

This warning is turned off by default but Google put warning as errors to  be sure that anyone can build with their product. You could turn it off but Microsoft says that it would be safer to disable sign extension manually if the error occurs when casting a pointer type which is what's occurring here.

On my side, I ended up modifying the code that was generating the error with:

```
// Disable this code for cross compiling on 32 bits machine
// GTEST_OS_WINDOWS will always be defined when compiling on a Windows machine.
// GTEST_OS_TARGET_PLATFORM is defined by us when running CMake
#if GTEST_OS_WINDOWS && !GTEST_OS_TARGET_PLATFORM
        *os << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(
          reinterpret_cast<internal::UInt64>(p));
#else
        *os << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(
          static_cast<internal::UInt64>(
            reinterpret_cast<internal::UInt32>(p)));
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy the whole error log in a single file and look for "error" tags. You will find something relevant like a header file not declared or forward declaration of an object, undefined reference. This error has nothing to do with gtest.